# Saving and showing again the View an user selected

Tags: javascript, forms, dynamics-crm-2011

I've been pulling my hair on what I thought was a simple issue.

I have a Product grid in an Entity form. 
Users can pick a view or create a custom view on the fly. 
I would like to persist this selection and show it again on form reopen (or refresh).

I'm currently saving three values about the currently selected view: viewid, view title and the so-called "effective fetchxml" (as found in the gridXml property).

As soon as I open the form, I try to reapply these values to the grid and .refresh() it, but to no avail.

Something tells me I'm overlooking a silly flag in the form editor - is this the case? Or what other options do I have?

Thanks

Comment: How are you applying the new values to the grid? Are you doing it the same way when you 'create a custom view on the fly' as when you load the page? Some code snippets might help.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution from [this blog post](http://crmgreenbible.blogspot.com/2011/07/crm-2011-change-subgrid-fetchxml.html): Assume you have a function that applies the changes called 'UpdateGridView()'. The concept you are missing is to check to see if the grid is loaded already or not.

```
if (grid ==null || grid.readyState != "complete") {
    //The subgrid hasn't loaded, wait 1 second and then try again     
    setTimeout('UpdateGridView()', 1000);     
    return; 
}
```

EDIT: spelling/grammar